# Why does the following python code not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, csv

I am very new to python and I have been working on this for a while now. I used the while loop and it worked, but I am trying it again and it does not seem to work for some reason. The code loops but nothing happens even when the time in the CSV file is reached. The code also works when not using loops, and just running it at the time in the CSV file.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import webbrowser
import csv

#Open CSV file
with open("/Users/3021118/Applications/URL-Opener/timings.csv", "rt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        
        while True:
            #Declares 'now' as the current time
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            
            #Opens up URL
            if lines[0] == now:
                meetinglink = lines[1]
                webbrowser.open(meetinglink)
                time.sleep(60)
                print('MEETING JOINED!')
```

This is what timings.csv looks like

[image]

Comment: `while True:` is an infinite loop. Your code will read the _first_ line from `csv_reader` and then get stuck in the `while True:` loop forever

Comment: I suggest adding more `print()` statements to understand what this code is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you mixed up the order with your "while True" loop and your for loop?
Your code will look at the first line (which is the titles) and then keeps checking if timings==now.

Try using the while true loop outside the open CSV file like so:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import webbrowser
import csv

while True:

    #Open CSV file
    with open("/Users/3021118/Applications/URL-Opener/timings.csv", "rt") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for lines in csv_reader:
        
            #Declares 'now' as the current time
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            
            #Opens up URL
            if lines[0] == now:
                meetinglink = lines[1]
                webbrowser.open(meetinglink)
                time.sleep(60)
                print('MEETING JOINED!')
```

You might wanna look at a condition for break() so your code doesn't run indefinetly.

Comment: Pranav Hosangadi explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that your first line is a header line, so `lines[0]` will be `"timings"` and never equal to a time formatted into a string, so you should skip that line right after opening the `csv_reader` like so:

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
```

Your code doesn't move forward because, like others have mentioned, it stays inside the `while True` loop for the first link forever. You probably forgot to `break` out of that loop when you join the meeting, so that the outer `for lines in csv_reader` loop can go to the next iteration.  You also want to sleep for a minute when the time isn't the right time so that you can go to the next minute.

```
         while True:
            #Declares 'now' as the current time
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
            
            #Opens up URL
            if lines[0] == now:
                meetinglink = lines[1]
                webbrowser.open(meetinglink)
                print('MEETING JOINED!')
                time.sleep(60)
                break; ### <<---- Break out of while True after joining meeting

            time.sleep(60)  ### <<---- sleep even when you didn't start the meetibng
```

---

However, this isn't a great way to do what you want, because it means if you start running your script after the time for the first meeting, you need to wait almost an entire day until the time is equal to the time of the first meeting. You want to *look up* the meeting link for the current time. This situation is very well suited to using a dictionary.

First, we read all lines of the csv file and create a lookup dictionary

```
zoom_links = dict()
with open("/Users/3021118/Applications/URL-Opener/timings.csv", "rt") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        zoom_links[line[0]] = line[1]
```

Now `zoom_links` looks like this:

```
{
 '07:50': 'https://zoom.link1',
 '08:30': 'https://zoom.link2',
 '09:30': 'https://zoom.link3'
}
```

Next, we can have a *separate* `while True` loop that opens the correct link at the correct time:

```
while True:
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    meetinglink = zoom_links.get(now, None) # Get the item at zoom_links[now], or None if no link for the current time

    if meetinglink is not None:
        webbrowser.open(meetinglink)
        print(f"Meeting {meetinglink} joined!")
    
    time.sleep(60)
```

---

Note: I didn't feel like transcribing your image into text, so I made this dummy csv file. You should post your input files [as formatted text](/help/formatting) instead of an image so that people can easily copy your inputs to their environments to ensure their code gives the expected result.

```
timings,meetinglink
07:50,https://zoom.link1
08:30,https://zoom.link2
09:30,https://zoom.link3
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you should remove

```
while True:
```

from your code or you should use  `break` to terminate the inner while loop.
so control will reach to `for`  loop. inside the `if` you can use `break`.

Answer (score -1):

When you read the CSV file with the headers it gets stuck in the loop. Because timing and meetingUrl are not match time such as 14:50. Read file without header. So, pd or df libraries could better for header=None.

Comment: I don't think that is the case because I've set it to just match the time so it would read it and ignore it.

Comment: It's seen CSV file has header and thought it's stuck. It would be another error. As said the status was missing to go out to while loop.